# Add parent and order feature in php cms

Tags: php, content-management-system

We have created a cms in php and we need to integrate the parent and order feature just like in wordpress. How do we do this? Help is really appreciated thanks. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK5Na.jpg

Answer (score 1):

add two new fields into your database table named `parent_id` and `order` where `parent_id` hold the id of the parent if its parent in its own then add `0` as parent_id to identify that current record is parent.

Now for `order` field add integer value for that so you can track at which order page or record will be displayed.

Comment: thanks. what is the php code do in need to add so those features will be added after i created the 2 new fields in my database?

Comment: @AGerry well not much, for adding you need to pass two more parameter into insert query, and you need to add code accordingly when displaying them....